# I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, django, csv

Code is cleaner here.  Please take look at:

```
def data_report_admin(csv_id):
    foranalyse = Reports.objects.get(pk=csv_id)
    path_csv = foranalyse.file.path
    with open(path_csv, 'rb') as csvfile:
        excelreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        k =1
        for row in excelreader:
            pprint.pprint(row)
```

Everything above for loop is working fine, but after throwing below error

```
I/O operation on closed file
```

Why am I getting that?

The code is perfectly working in `django view function.`

The workflow here is... Admin can upload file to the server using `save_model`, then after save return to `data_report_admin(csv_id)` function to perform and parsing csv file and save those value into database.

Comment: Which line is throwing this error?

Comment: @Tichodroma `for row in excelreader:` throwing error....

Comment: Can you try `open(path_csv, "rb")` and just `read` from it without using `csv`?

Comment: @Tichodroma like this `excelreader = csvfile.read` ..? but same error here also

Comment: So you can not read from this file. Do you have the permissions? Does it exist?

Comment: oh.. you think this because of the `permission` ..? It's coming from the db after save ... tell is there anyway to check permission ? and also i given the exact file path ...

Comment: @Tichodroma i changed file permission using `os.chmod(path_csv, 777)` but that's not helped me .. Any solution..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are doing that in admin.py file..?

Just return the id `data_report(csv_id)` Here data_report is view function ...